# convert separate date and time strings to datetime c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time

I have a csv table with two cells: Date and time:

| objectID | Time | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 07:22 AM | Bonbon | 2022-03-14 |
| 1 | 03:15 PM | Pie | 2022-03-23 |

I am trying to combine the date time such as: `DateTime bonbonTime = "2022-03-14 07:22 AM"`
I could just do that like such:

```
string bonbonTimeString = 
    table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Time) 
    + " " 
    + table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Date)
DateTime bonbonTime = DateTime.ParseExact(bonbonTimeString, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, as this is in a loop, I try to avoid too many string conversions. So I tried this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Date));
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Time));
DateTime dateTime = date.AddTicks(time.Ticks);
```

Turns out that `time` won't equal to `7:22 AM` but to `2022-06-10 07:22 AM` (today) so the end result is in year 2044. What would be the performance efficient way of doing that?

Comment: You should convert the time in a timespan and then add the timespan to the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would stick with the concatenation (assuming the dates and times are always in the same format), just because this way it will only need to be parsed once. I would do something like the following:

```cs
string date = table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Date);
string time = table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Time);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse($"{date} {time}");
```

If you don't want to do it this way and would rather splice two datetimes together, you could get your current example to work just by subtracting `DateTime.Today` (the current date at midnight) from your `time` which will make it a `TimeSpan` representing the time you need to add to your date. This would look something like the following:

```cs
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Date));
DateTime timeToday = DateTime.Parse(table.GetCell(searchIndex, Headers.Time));
TimeSpan time = timeToday - DateTime.Today;
DateTime dateTime = date + time;
```

Neither of these methods are insanely performance intensive, so it really won't make much of a difference which one you use. However, I think first one is very slightly faster just because it only needs to parse the string once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix custom and standard format strings, so `"yyyy-MM-dd t"` will not work as your format. You need to specify the time format exactly:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(bonbonTimeString, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```